# dbt | bigquery - Grouping by expressions of type STRUCT is not allowed

Tags: google-bigquery, dbt

guys.

I am new to dbt and also bigquery. I have a simple data pipeline that gets information from 3 tables and creates a new one with the data that i want to show. The query in bigquery:

```
select sta.status, concat(dri.forename, ' ' ,dri.surname) driver_name, count(sta.status) as number_of_fails
    from `dts_staging_f1_data.results` res
    inner join `dts_staging_f1_data.status` sta on sta.statusId = res.statusId
    inner join `dts_staging_f1_data.drivers` dri on dri.driverId = res.driverId
    where res.statusId not in (1, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 45, 50, 128,53,55,58,88,111,112,113,114,115,116,117,118,119,120,122,123,124,125,127,133,134)
    group by sta.status, dri.forename, dri.surname
    having count(sta.status) > 1
    order by count(sta.status) desc, sta.status ;
```

[query result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0UMl.png)

However, making the transformation via dbt i get this:

```
with results as (
    select statusId, driverId from `omitted-project-id`.`dts_staging_f1_data`.`results`
),
 ref_status as (
    select status,statusId from `omitted-project-id`.`dts_staging_f1_data`.`status`
),
drivers as (
    select driverId,forename, surname from `omitted-project-id`.`dts_staging_f1_data`.`drivers`
),

final as (
    select ref_status.status, concat(drivers.forename, ' ', drivers.surname) as driver_name, count(ref_status.status) as number_of_fails
    from results
    inner join ref_status using (statusId)
    inner join drivers using (driverId)
    where results.statusId not in (1, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 45, 50, 128,53,55,58,88,111,112,113,114,115,116,117,118,119,120,122,123,124,125,127,133,134)
    group by ref_status.status, drivers.forename, drivers.surname
    order by count(ref_status.status) desc, ref_status.status 
)

select * from final
```

The same query, transformed, i get this error:
[query result after dbt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmzBD.png)

I guess that dbt is making some kind of transforming the status table into STRUCT but i don't know why. Can somebody help me?

The models.yml look like this:

```
version: 2

sources:
  - name: src-bq-de-f1-project
    schema: dts_staging_f1_data
    tables: 
      - name: results
      - name: status
      - name: drivers
```

Thank you.

Comment: Any particular reasons you are using different query structure in dbt? What happens if you put the original query in your dbt model? My gut feel is this might be something to do with the way Bigquery handles CTEs.

Comment: dbt is essentially running the query on BigQuery, so the problem is not in dbt but in how you are setting up the query. The error msg mentions that you are trying to group by a `struct` field, which by definition cannot be grouped by because it may contain different data types inside. Are you sure you are applying the same transformations upstream?

Comment: Thank you both, for trying to help! :) I did test with the original query and it works. Then i thought changing everything until it breaks. And only the status table is the one getting me trouble. 
I have no idea why :(

When works: https://i.postimg.cc/X7GKbzLq/img.png